# Creating a label dynamically on a view controller makes it reset in Xcode

Tags: xcode, reset, addsubview

I've been searching about the addsubview function and I've found someone saying that the usage of that function actually makes the view controller to reset itself and of course all the previous created objects.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)CrearEst:(id)sender {
    for(int i=0; i< 10; i++)
    {
        float x = arc4random() %300;
        //float x = arc4random() %300;
        UILabel *estrella = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 4, 4)];
        estrella.tag = i;
        estrella.center = CGPointMake(x,100);
        estrella.text = @".";
        estrella.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.view insertSubview:(estrella) atIndex: 0];
    }
}
```

That works great, but the problem is that, like I said before, all the previous created objects, and it's positions are reseted so when I move my Character and I execute that function, the object come backs to the middle of the screen again and again.

If there's actually another way of doing this I would be pleased to hear it!

SOLUTION: I've find after hours of trying that the solution is to replace "self.view" with "self.view.superview" so you'll have something like this

```
[self.view.superview insertSubview:(estrella) atIndex: 0]
```

The usage of "superview" instead of view resolved the problem.

See you!